# Azure NextMarker

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have created a container in Azure called files. It has 3 images and 2 txt files.

https://attosolstorage.blob.core.windows.net/files?comp=list

With the URL listed above, NextMarker will be empty. If I use the following URL..

https://attosolstorage.blob.core.windows.net/files?comp=list&maxresults=1

It shows the NextMarker field populated, and what I understand from [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179352.aspx#Samplerequestandresponse) is that using NextMarker as a QueryString should give me the 2nd object. However, this URL gives the same output as the previous one.

https://attosolstorage.blob.core.windows.net/files?comp=list&maxresults=1&nextmarker=1!16!aW1nL3JlZC5qcGc-

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the query string parameter is **`marker`** and not **`nextmarker`** (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135734.aspx) :).

So if you try: https://attosolstorage.blob.core.windows.net/files?comp=list&maxresults=1&marker=1!16!aW1nL3JlZC5qcGc-, things should work just fine.